# How to use more complex datasource with UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, ios, uipickerview

How to use complex datasource with UIPickerView? I've got an array of objects and want to use MyObject.Name as caption of element in UIPickerView, but get the whole object back when it's selected.

it's an NSMutableArray of objects.

`

```
@interface Account : NSObject
{
    NSString *ID;
    NSString *Name;
    NSString *AccountTypeName;
    NSString *Type;
}
```

Array looks like this:

```
`2012-05-15 16:30:05.847 App[2320:f803] (
    "<Account: 0x6888d70>",
    "<Account: 0x6eb09a0>",
    "<Account: 0x6d7f170>",
    "<Account: 0x6d79ca0>"
)`
```

I`m getting a "unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6888d70'" error when i use it

Comment: can you please write content of array in your question.

Comment: it's an NSMutableArray of objects `@interface Account : NSObject
{
    NSString *ID;
    NSString *Name;
    NSString *AccountTypeName;
    NSString *Type;
}`

Comment: I don't find any of array in you interface(.h)file   If you don't understand my need please NSLog your array and then write that output here !!

Comment: i guess i've already see what`s the problem with array, i`ll check it right now

Comment: You have written bad o/p here based on that I can't help you !!! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store all your Object in an array
and in the function :

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

you find by name (with a NSPredicate by example) the selected item

OR :

```
[ARRAYNAME objectAtIndex:row]
```

Comment: then how should titleForRow look like?

Comment: it should looks like :

    [[ARRAYNAME] objectAtIndex:row] getName];